# How to get value from a specific cell in a gridview asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row

Previously I asked this question...

[Change the color of a row or record on a gridview on asp.net c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974025/change-the-color-of-a-row-or-record-on-a-gridview-on-asp-net-c)

I'm trying out one of those answers, however now I stumbled upon a problem...

before assigning a color to the row, first I must make sure that both the field Estado equals to "Pendiente", and that the field Fecha (which is a date) is lower that today's date...

I just can't find a way to get those couple of values out of the `gridview`

I need to do this for every row, so I'm usin the one that involves `RowDataBound`

Comment: I guess `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text` should do the trick.

Comment: Which type of datasource you use (DataTable, List of classes...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

than you show need to just check the text value of cell of gridrow.

like in your rowbound if the its `BoundColumn`

```
string value = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;//here 1 is you column number
```

if there is `TemplateColumn` and contains control like label than

```
string value = (e.Row.FindControl("lableid") as Label).Text;
```

than write your login.