# header for colur and header columns separatpor should have different colurs in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how to make gridview header fore color white and header column separator should have black color in gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVProformainvoice" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="701px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3B4E87" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="2px">
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="black" ForeColor="white"/>
```

Comment: javascript can help you to do this

Comment: can u tell me how to do that..any idea?

Comment: by the way css also can do the same question

Comment: waiting for a moment , I will try it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my example is for front end solutions , and it is a very easy sample to you , hopefully it is you want , by using javascript with css

PS: by the way  in fact you can add Css to your gridview ,it is more easy way to deal with your problem with front end . to check [GridView group rows and change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933651/gridview-group-rows-and-change-color) ,if you want to use back end solution.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb3212">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function color(){
                var table = document.getElementById("person");
                var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    if(i % 2 == 0){
                        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#EAF2D3";
                    }
                    else{
                        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "White";
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #person {
            border-style: 1px solid;
            border-color: blue;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: auto;
        }

            #person th {
                border: 1px solid;
                padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
                background-color: #A7C942;
                color: #ffffff;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #person td {
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                text-align: center;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="person" align="center" width="90%" height="200">
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aa</td>            
            <td>33333333</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bb</td>            
            <td>44444444</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cc</td>            
            <td>55555555</td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dd</td>
            <td>66666666</td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>



Only CSS    

<table class="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>aa</td><td>aa</td></tr>
        <tr><td>bb</td><td>bb</td></tr>
        <tr><td>cc</td><td>cc</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dd</td><td>dd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ee</td><td>ee</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    .myTable {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

        .myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #CCC;
        }

        .myTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #FFF;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: but im using gridview, not general table

Comment: Bind datatable to GridView

Comment: @krishnamohan if you want use back-end to deal with your question, please check this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933651/gridview-group-rows-and-change-color